# 401 unauthorized for one client but not for the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, authorization, iis-7.5

I have a Web API that serves two MVC apps. All 3 run under IIS 7.5.

**App A**: Anonymous authentication only, behind ADFS. IIS standalone website.

**App B**: Windows authentication only. Application under another IIS website.

**API:**

- Windows authentication only
- members of a security group X authorized access  App A and App B
- application pool accounts of App A and App B added to security group X

The issue is that App A can access the API just fine, but App B gets 401 unauthorized.

If I remove the authorization restriction on the API, App B can access it too. But of course I need this authorization in place to protect the API from unauthorized access.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set "Load User Profile" to true in the IIS app pool for App B. Found out by comparing both application pools.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/